# vbscript open folder in same explorer window

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am not so good in VBScript at all, but thanks to Google I was able to put together script which is able to open file path in explorer.exe

I would like to open the specific path in same window not in the new one. Is VBScript able to do it?

Here is my code:

```
Dim SH, FolderToOpen 
Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
FolderToOpen = "C:\path\to\my\folder" 
SH.Run FolderToOpen 
Set SH = Nothing
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hackish approach using `SendKeys` that will work if the open instance of `explorer.exe` has the focus:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
target = "C:/programs"
WshShell.SendKeys "%d"
WshShell.SendKeys target
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

This will work if you e.g. have the above code (with the intended target) in a script in one folder. Click on the script icon and it will send you to the target folder.

[On Edit] An explanation of how it works: If you are using Windows Explorer and type `Alt+d` (which is what `SendKeys "%d"` simulates) then the focus is shifted to the address bar. For years I have been using this trick to open a command prompt in the current folder (`Alt - d` then type `cmd` then press `Enter` and the prompt opens with the open folder as the working directory). When I saw this question I wondered if essentially the same trick (but automated with VBScript) would work for navigation purposes and was pleasantly surprised when it worked as intended the very first time. `Alt-d` is a useful keyboard shortcut to keep in mind.

Comment: awesome, working like a charm! thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run Target
```